# Kinect on Jetson TK1

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, kinect, freenect, jetson

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I cannot get Kinect (PC edition) to be detected with ROS (indigo) freenect_launch.
Ubuntu (using grinch kernel) packaged freenect_glview does give me Kinect image and depth information, ROS glview does not find device.

```
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 045e:02bf Microsoft Corp.
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 045e:02be Microsoft Corp.
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 045e:02c2 Microsoft Corp.
```

Thanks for hints.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195168/kinect-on-jetson-tk1/) by [cc_smart](https://answers.ros.org/users/20489/cc_smart/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-10-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like the version of libfreenect that is included in ROS is currently too old to support the Kinect4Windows.

There is an [open ticket](https://github.com/ros-drivers/freenect_stack/issues/12) about this.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cc_smart](https://answers.ros.org/users/20489/cc_smart/) on 2014-10-20**:
Thanks for reply !
Unfortunately neither of these worked for me, but if I understand correctly, Kinect does work for you in the Jetson ?
I'm wondering if the USB id values do not match "expectations" of the library coming with ROS ? What Kinect edition / USB ID values do you use / see ?
Thanks again

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-20**:
Yes, I have an original Kinect.

**Comment by [cc_smart](https://answers.ros.org/users/20489/cc_smart/) on 2014-10-20**:
If the note regarding freenect version and recommendation for bugtracker ticket was pulled out, I believe I can give that the "correct answer" mark.
I believe this can added as bugtracker link: [Ticket](https://github.com/ros-drivers/freenect_stack/issues/12)